# Set cell string based on numerical value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel 2010 sheet with a column that can contain any number. I'd like to populate another column with a text string based on this: -

If A1="1" then A2="Yes"

If A1="any other value" then A2="No"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple IF will do it:

```
=IF(A1=1,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! Do you know if the formula or the string will remain in the cell if I save as a csv?

Comment: I believe you will lose the formula and keep the value.  Not sure.  You will need to test it.

Comment: It works well, just the string is saved :-)